# Mysql Datetime save Time

Tags: java, php, mysql

Here is the scenario :

I have a form :

| Check in  time |

| Check out time |

E.G i do :

Check in = 15:30

Check out = 16:30

Questions :

1. How can i store the times in my mysql Table which is styled in "datetime" (YY-MM-DD 10:45:48)

Will this work ?:

```
Date datum = new Date();
//today declared as today
 datum.setDay(today);
 datum.setMonth(today);
 datum.setYear(today);

 datum.setMinute(30);
 datum.setHour(15);
```

and then " insert date='date' "

2nd :

How can I Delete via MYSQL the row which Time is Smaller than current:

Will this work?

```
DELETE FROM adminLoginLog WHERE `date` > NOW() );
```

Note im useing MysqlI <--- not mysql

Comment: Are you manually building the SQL statement, or are you using JDBC's [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) interface? `PreparedStatement`s are created via the `Connection` object's [`prepareStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)) methods.  See: [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more info.

Comment: The reason I ask is because PrepareStatement has methods for sending various datatypes to the server based on the DB driver.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Java, use `java.sql.Timestamp` to store the date and time of your field. Also, build your `Date` using `Calendar` object, do not update fields in `java.util.Date` directly. Note that using `new Date()` will automatically create a `java.util.Date` with the current date and time, no need to do any special additional effort.
2. Try this query (assumming this is what you want):

   ```
   DELETE FROM adminLoginLog WHERE `date` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND NOW()
   ```

   In case you only need the current time (really odd), use `CURTIME()`:

   ```
   DELETE FROM adminLoginLog WHERE `date` < CURTIME()
   ```

Comment: 1. Oh great works   2.nd i want to check if Date Colum of the row is lower than current dateime

Comment: @user3110458 so current time only? Because `date` name seems to store both `date` and `time`.

Comment: ...it's a bit presumptuous to assume this is a `java.util.Date` instead of a `java.sql.Date`.